# Returning an array from function which reads from file

Tags: python-2.7

my first question here.
How do you get an array which you saved in variable from function that is reading my txt file.
Ty.

```
def reading(a):
    read = open(a, "r")
    rows = read.readlines()
    print(rows)
    read.close()
    return rows

reading("datoteka.txt")
print(reading)
```

Basically I get this as output:
['prvi red\n', '25\n', 'treci red\n', 'cetvrti red']
[function reading at 0x02B13B70>

Answer (score 1):

You didn't save the return value of `reading("datoteka.txt")`, and you printed the function object `reading`.  Instead of those last two lines, you want:

```
data = reading("datoteka.txt")
print(data)
```